# How to pass variable to const char type?

Tags: c++, arduino

```
void printLCD(int col, int row , const char *str) {
    for(int i=0 ; i < strlen(str) ; i++){
      lcd.setCursor(col+i , row);
      lcd.print(str[i]);
    }
}

void loop(){
    lightAmount = analogRead(0);
    
    // Here
    printLCD(0, 0, printf("Light amount: %d", lightAmount ));
}
```

I'm newbie to c language for arduino project.

I want to show `"Light Amount: 222"` to LCD.

But 3rd parameter in `printLCD` function, it could receive string type only, so an error occurred.

How can I display variable and string together in above case?

Comment: Use the Arduino [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class to handle strings. Oh yeah, Arduino is programmed in C++, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` doesn't return the string, it prints it to a standard output which is not configured on most Arduinos by default.

You can use [snprintf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) C function to format a string in Arduino sketch.

```
void printLCD(int col, int row , const char *str) {
  lcd.setCursor(col, row);
  lcd.print(str);
}

void loop(){
    lightAmount = analogRead(0);
    
    char str[17]; // for 16 positions of the LCD + terminating 0
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "Light amount:%d", lightAmount);
    printLCD(0, 0, str);

   delay(100);
}
```

---

Some LCD display libraries support `print` function for numbers. Then you can do

```
void loop(){
  lightAmount = analogRead(0);
    
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Light amount:");
  lcd.print(lightAmount);

  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now LCD print what I wanted properly. But, if the light sensor value changed 1023 ===> 300, the last number of 1023, "3" is not disappeared. so LCD print 3003. If the number changed like 4 digits to 3 digits, last number of 4 digits still left. Do you know why these happen? Could I register this to question? Thanks again :)

Comment: You could use the "%-4d" format in the `snprintf` call to get a number that always takes 4 positions and is left justified. Or "%4d" for a right justified number. Also... careful with sizing the temporary buffer... it's easy to overflow it and stomp on something else.

Comment: @aMike, it is `snprintf` which doesn't overflow